# Why does CSS transition-duration not work on child elment?

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition

I have a problem that my transition does not get applied on an absolute positon child div.

Here is my codepen:

https://codepen.io/Data-Mastery/pen/oNvRdGv

On line 213 (`&:hover .image`) in the SASS file I want to scale the image and also set a filter, which works fine, but the transition-duration does not get applied.

If I just apply the hover statement on the parent element and not the image, the transition works fine. What is wrong here, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a transition to the .image class (or to the hover function, whatever you want to achieve)

```
      &:hover .image {
        transform: scale(1.1);
        filter: grayscale(50%);
        transition: your parameter;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add transition property to the

```
& .image {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
        transition:0.5s;
      }
```

This will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Why man , it works see this:-

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap");
@keyframes moveInLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-200px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateX(10px);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes moveInRight {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(200px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateX(-10px);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes moveInBottom {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(100px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.leftanimation {
  animation: moveInLeft 1.2s forwards;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4rem;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

p {
  margin: 0.75rem;
}

.l-heading-light {
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.l-heading-dark {
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: #c2453b;
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.primary-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #c2453b;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
.primary-btn:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #c2453b;
  transform: translateY(-3px);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.primary-btn:active {
  transform: translateY(-1px);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  z-index: 1;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar__nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.navbar__nav li a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  margin: 0 0.25rem;
}
.navbar__nav li a:hover {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #333;
}

.showcase {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(194, 69, 59, 0.4), rgba(178, 86, 65, 0.4)), url("https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/hiking-forest-man-morning-mist-travel-concept-45457025.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
.showcase__content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.showcase__content p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  animation: moveInRight 1.2s forwards;
}
.showcase__content a {
  animation: moveInBottom 1.2s 0.8s linear backwards;
}

#tours {
  text-align: center;
  background: #f7f7f7;
}
#tours .container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  max-width: 1200px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
  color: #fff;
}
#tours .container .card {
  position: relative;
  height: 35rem;
  width: 20rem;
  margin: 2rem 1rem;
  padding: 0;
  background: #b25641;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#tours .container .card:hover .image {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
#tours .container .card .image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}
#tours .container .card__content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 15rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <title>Malamar Hotels</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <h1 class="navbar__logo">
        Malamar
      </h1>
      <ul class="navbar__nav">
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Tours</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <header class="showcase">
      <div class="showcase__content">
        <h1 class="l-heading-light leftanimation">
          Hiking this fall
        </h1>
        <p>
          Book the best hikings tours for this fall in beautiful areas across
          europe
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="primary-btn">See our tours</a>
      </div>
    </header>

    <section id="tours">
      <h1 class="l-heading-dark">Our best offers</h1>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/hiking-forest-man-morning-mist-travel-concept-45457025.jpg" alt="Hi" class="image" />
          <div class="card__content">
            <h1>Hiking</h1>
            <p>2-day tour</p>
            <a href="#" class="primary-btn">Book now!</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/hiking-forest-man-morning-mist-travel-concept-45457025.jpg" alt="Hi" class="image" />
          <div class="card__content">
            <h1>Rafting tour</h1>
            <p>3-day tour</p>
            <a href="#" class="primary-btn">Book now!</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/hiking-forest-man-morning-mist-travel-concept-45457025.jpg" alt="Hi" class="image" />
          <div class="card__content">
            <h1>Mountainbiking</h1>
            <p>5-day tour</p>
            <a href="#" class="primary-btn">Book now!</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

  </body>
</html>
```